# Why I can't echo information from database in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I was trying to echo information from database, but somehow it's just doesn't work. It only show the categories in the output page, but nothing from the database.

```
<?php
     $con = mysql_connect( 'localhost', 'USERNAME', 'PASSWORD' )
         or die(mysql_error());
     $db = mysql_select_db('bestluw_luckydog') 
         or die(mysql_error());
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM Chihuahua";
     $query = mysql_query( $sql);


     while ( $info = mysql_fetch_array($query) );
    {
          echo '<b>Name:</b>' .$info['name'] . "<br>";
          echo '<b>Age:</b>' .$info['age'] . "<br>";
          echo '<b>Breed:</b>' .$info['breed'] . "<br>";
          echo '<b>Sex:</b>' .$info['he'] . "<br>";
          echo '<b>Color:</b>' .$info['color'] . "<br>";
          echo '<b>Size:</b>' .$info['size'] . "<br>";
          echo '<b>When:</b>' .$info['when'] . "<br>";
          echo '<b>Special:</b>' .$info['special'] . "<br>";
    }


   ?>
```

Comment: @andershagbard that edit won't help much. The password is still in the revisions history.

Comment: Stop using mysql_* (it is deprecated) and start using mysqli or PDO.

Comment: Sadly, "it just doesn't work" isn't a very useful error message. It looks like the answer has been identified below, but if you can be more specific with questions in the future, it makes life a lot simpler for people assisting. Thanks.

Comment: @MaciejSz However, not visible unless you search for it.

Answer (score 4):

Try to remove

```
 while ( $info = mysql_fetch_array($query) );
```

; from this line.

If you steal no output - your DB table is empty.

Read about PDO, mysql_query will be deprecated in the next PHP release.

Answer (score 1):

```
while ($info = mysql_fetch_array($query)) //remove semicolon
    {
          echo '<b>Name:</b>' .$info['name'] . "<br>";
          echo '<b>Age:</b>' .$info['age'] . "<br>";
          echo '<b>Breed:</b>' .$info['breed'] . "<br>";
          echo '<b>Sex:</b>' .$info['he'] . "<br>";
          echo '<b>Color:</b>' .$info['color'] . "<br>";
          echo '<b>Size:</b>' .$info['size'] . "<br>";
          echo '<b>When:</b>' .$info['when'] . "<br>";
          echo '<b>Special:</b>' .$info['special'] . "<br>";
    }
```